# Can't use ADB at all

Tags: adb, windows-11

I have very weird problems with ADB which I can't start or kill ADB server at all.

This is what I get when I try to use `adb start-server` (with `set ADB_TRACE=all`)

```
E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools>adb start-server
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_trace.cpp:187] Running on Windows 10.0.22621
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_client.cpp:351] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 07-09 16:41:13  9808  9160 adb_client.cpp:160] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 07-09 16:41:15  9808  9160 sysdeps_win32.cpp:1032] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다. (10061)
adb D 07-09 16:41:15  9808  9160 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error code 10061 to errno 22
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb D 07-09 16:41:15 12680  8312 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-09 16:41:15 12680  8312 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb D 07-09 16:41:15 12680  8312 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 07-09 16:41:15 12680  8312 adb_trace.cpp:187] Running on Windows 10.0.22621
adb D 07-09 16:41:15 12680  8312 adb_trace.cpp:187]
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
adb D 07-09 16:41:17  9808  9160 sysdeps_win32.cpp:151] _fh_from_int: invalid fd -2 passed to adb_close
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Common workaround is executing `adb kill-server`. This is what I get when I execute it.

```
E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools>adb kill-server
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_trace.cpp:187] Running on Windows 10.0.22621
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 07-09 16:41:42  2500  2188 adb_client.cpp:199] adb_kill_server
adb D 07-09 16:41:44  2500  2188 sysdeps_win32.cpp:1032] could not connect to tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다. (10061)
adb D 07-09 16:41:44  2500  2188 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error code 10061 to errno 22
cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못 했습니다. (10061)
```

It seems something is using `tcp:5037`.

But I don't see any program occupying TCP port 5037. Nothing is printed when I run `netstat -aon | findstr 5037`, `tasklist | findstr 5037` and `tasklist | findstr adb` even with Administrator privilege. I even tried NMAP but still I don't see any program using that port.

So I tried to use another port with adb. I tried `adb -P 12345 start-server`.

```
E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools>adb -P 12345 start-server
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_trace.cpp:187] Running on Windows 10.0.22621
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_trace.cpp:187]
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_client.cpp:351] adb_connect: service: host:start-server
adb D 07-09 16:48:17 13240  8404 adb_client.cpp:160] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 13240  8404 sysdeps_win32.cpp:1032] could not connect to tcp:12345: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:12345: 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다. (10061)
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 13240  8404 sysdeps_win32.cpp:602] _socket_set_errno: mapping Windows error code 10061 to errno 22
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:12345
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 10032 10072 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 10032 10072 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 34.0.3-10161052
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 10032 10072 adb_trace.cpp:187] Installed as E:\DOWNLOAD\platform-tools\adb.exe
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 10032 10072 adb_trace.cpp:187] Running on Windows 10.0.22621
adb D 07-09 16:48:19 10032 10072 adb_trace.cpp:187]
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
adb D 07-09 16:48:20 13240  8404 sysdeps_win32.cpp:151] _fh_from_int: invalid fd -2 passed to adb_close
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Same error happened.

These are what else I've tried:

- Change extension of every other ADB executables
  This is less destructive than deleting them because they can't be launched anyway
- Disable AdGuard and terminate it
- Disable Windows Defender Firewall
- Disable Windows Defender protection
- Allow port 5037 for inbound, outbound, TCP, UDP

I really don't know what to do else. Even Google couldn't help me for this strange behavior.

Re-installing Windows would be final choice, but I doubt it would help because I've experiencing this issue even before re-installing Windows few weeks ago.

Comment: First you should check if the adb server instance was started at all. Use Taskmanager or Sysinternal Process Explorer and search for the server process (command-line similar to `adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 584`). You can also check Windows application and system event log it it contains any entries when you try to start adb. Last bt not least you can use Sysinternal process Monitor to check process creation how long the adb server process survives.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with `ucrtbase.dll` but that's very strange because this problem kept happening before full-wipe and re-installing Windows... And I can confirm that there is no ADB process is running at the moment.

Comment: It seems `ucrtbase.dll` is installed by Windows SDK which I don't have it installed, but that's very weird behavior because I don't see any Windows SDK requirements in Google's 'platform-tools' download page. Isn't it just for debugging, rather than actually setup adb daemon?

Comment: `ucrtbase.dll` is part of Windows and many application. May be an old app has replaced the system version(s) with outdated versions? Run `sfc /scannow` . Which Windows version do you use 10 or 11? My Win10 system32 version (64bit) has SHA-1 hash `E82945E3E63FFEF0974D6DD74F2AEF2BF6D0A908` WoW64 version (32bit) has `54D14ACE2F00A93C28984A577EBB47929D29E3CF`.

Comment: SFC restored Edge Dev Client stuff, but I still can't use ADB at all. I use Windows 11. It seems there is two `ucrtbase.dll` in my system. One is inside of `system32` and the other one is inside of `Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun`. Their size are different so I guess they are kind of conflicting with each other. But there is no way that I can fix it, because the second one would be installed with MS Office (I guess)

Comment: I don't think you have searched the whole system. Windows 11 is AFAIR only available as 64 bit system and thus it contains at least two times `ucrtbase.dll` in C:\Windows subdirs.

Comment: If I scan the whole system/drive, there are tons of `ucrtbase.dll`. It can be founded in Java, foobar2000, MS Office, Steam, system32 and syswow64, WinSxS etc. At that case, I don't think I can figure out which `ucrtbase.dll` should be inspected. At least, SFC scan result tells me system integrity is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that I couldn't use ADB for this...

I symlinked `%UserProfile%\.android` directory to other drive before. Let's say that the destination directory is `E:\.android`.

At the time when I was trying to use `adb`, `E:\.android` directory was not present. Since `%UserProfile%\.android` was still present (but with non-existent destination), ADB couldn't create new `.android` directory. This prevented ADB to create new `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` file.

Since ADB couldn't create required files, it failed to process `start-server`. And since there was no running ADB server, `kill-server` also failed.

I created `E:\.android` and ADB runs without any problem.

This is weird because ADB recognized my device as `offline`(very old version of ADB) and `unauthorized`(old version of ADB), but not in latest version of ADB.

---

TL;DR

Check if `%UserProfile%\.android` is valid directory and accessible.